# How does Ajax work in Rails 5 when scaffolding a resource?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

When scaffolding a resource, say a `Post` you get some code that looks something like the following:

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:

```
# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I can render the `_form.html.erb` partial for the task in the index page:

app/views/posts/index.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'form', post: @post %>
```

And, if I go into the `_form.html.erb` partial I can add the `remote: true` option:

```
<%= form_for post, remote: true do |f| %>
```

And I'm able to successfully append a new post via an ajax request.

The line that's confusing to me is:

```
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
```

What is going on in this line? For example looking at [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-sns5tNdTY) from Mike at the pragmatic studios. He creates a `app/views/posts/create.js.erb` that has the javascript required to append the post. Is rails doing this automatically? What is the convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "remote: true" to the form would apply to format.js within your controller, and in the case of the video tutorial, execute an accompanying js.erb file.

format.json allows you, or more literally some sort of client app (mobile, javascript), to send a request in json and receive a json formatted response.  You can test this in one of your scaffolded 'show' actions by visiting localhost:3000/posts/1 (for the html format) and localhost:3000/posts/1.json (for the json format).